# Installation scripts doesn't work with sudo

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I'm a Fedora 32, but I'm a Linux user for a long time, and this is the first time I saw something like this. Every time I try to use any install script, from any program, I have several bash errors when I start the command with sudo, but with my normal user everything goes fine (obviously I have several permissions problems without sudo)

One example, there’s a Render Engine called Guerilla Render, and every time I try to use the install script using sudo, I have problems like this:

```
[moco@moco-fedora guerillarender]$ sudo ./install 
[sudo] password for moco: 
./install: line 23: dirname: command not found
./install: line 25: basename: command not found
./install: line 92: grep: command not found
./install: line 92: cut: command not found
./install: line 152: id: command not found
./install: line 152: [: too many arguments
./install: line 195: cat: command not found
./install: line 198: clear: command not found
Guerilla Render  Setup

Press any keys to continue
```

It's just an example, but it happens with any other program I try to install in the same way.

This is strange, cause I already have installed other programs in the same way, and everything went good. There’s a program called Houdini, and it’s the main tool for my work. I already installed it, and I tested the same installer now, and now it doesn’t work. Same version, it worked before, just don’t work anymore. It’s a recent problem

Any thoughts?

Comment: Check your `/etc/sudoers`  (and any files in `/etc/sudoers.d/` directory) configuration for `secure_path` entries or similar that will result in an empty path being defined.

Comment: Damn, ok I’ve found the problem. I had two environment variables, one in my .bashrc, at my Home folder, and another on /etc/environment. .bashrc > PATH="/opt/pixar/RenderManProServer-23.2/bin:$PATH" and /etc/environment > PATH="/opt/pixar/RenderManProServer-23.2/bin". One of then was messing up all my system. What is the right way to create an environment variable?

Comment: The form you used in `.bashrc` will *add* (prefix) the new pathname to the existing PATH value, while the form in your `/etc/environment` will *replace* any existing value with the new one. The latter probably caused your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by a messed up path environment variable that is active when you run `sudo`. Please check the output of `sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'`. It should contain both `/bin` and `/usr/bin`. If it doesn't, make sure `/etc/sudoers` or a file in `/etc/sudoers.d/` contains an entry like the following:

```
Defaults secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

Comment: Thank you Martin, you're right, I messed up my PATH editing my /etc/environment. I deleted the faulty entry and everything is working now

Comment: Good to hear. Consider [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to show others that this has been resolved.